# Why the workflow started date has a delay of 2 hours in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am using sharepoint 2010. I have created a document library. On this document library I have added a workflow. I uploaded a new document to my library and started manual the workflow. I can see the workflow is started and has the status "In Progress". I can see also in the GUI the started datetime "7/22/2014 12:21 PM". I would like to make some powershell  script which is try to get all running workflows which are older than 4 hours. But I see something strange when I get the created date of the workflow instance. I see a delay of 2 hours. See below the test results:

$workflow.Created returns : 7/22/2014 10:21:39 AM

SharePoint GUI returns: 7/22/2014 12:21 PM

[image]

Why powershell is giving me the wrong date? It is delayed for 2 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by my self. Powershell is using the UTC time. It is possible to convert it to the local time:

```
$workflow.Created.ToLocalTime()
```